# Offline Android connect to PHP localhost using only USB cable

Tags: php, android, json, okhttp

I'm trying to get JSON data from a PHP file (Apache/XAMPP) in localhost to Android using only a USB cable. The Android device is offline. Is it possible? Someone suggested using `okhttp3` but I can't figure out how to.

Comment: where you call `okhttp3` request ? device is offline means what ?

Comment: Please be more clear. What exactly do you mean by "my php"? Is it an Apache/XAMPP installation running in your PC?

Answer (score 0):

If not already tried, Try running the app from emulator first but with the IPv4 address from ipconfig(command promt).use the ipv4 address instead of "Localhost:8080" use "Localhost:" in your code.

Comment: An emulator with a usb cable?

Comment: No, Try running the app in emulator. not with USB cable in your android device. If it worked properly then you can know there is no issue with your code.

Comment: And why not try using wifi? And did you ever try with only a usb cable? The question is not if the code is correct but if only a usb cable can be used. Now did you do that before?

Comment: can use wifi. but device and system must be in same network and must call the webservice by using system's IPv4 address

Comment: Then now tell how to use a usb cable please. As that is the question.

Comment: USB doesn't provide network access to the device. so USB cable is not an option

Comment: Then why not post that as an answer instead of that irrelevant emulator stuff?

Comment: It was not irrelevant but an alternative. Just Tried to give a suggestion instead of just a abrupt "NO".